# Density Matrix in Quantum Optics

Tags: density-operator

I am studying laser physics and didn't get the whole idea of the density matrix (in this case for two-level systems). I know this is really basic so bear with me!

I understand that the diagonal elements represent the states <1| and <2| but what exactly do the coherences tell me and what is a coherent state? I know that a coherent state is a state that is not an energy eigenstate, but what does it mean in the case of a two-level system (like a laser)? Does it mean that neither the ground nor the excited state are populated?

I'd just like to grasp the physical meaning of all of this.

Comment: Welcome to physics.SE. Please consider splitting your question into two separating the question on the density matrix from the question on relaxation times.

Answer (score 1):

I assume by conherences you mean the off-diagonal elements in the density matrix. It isn't obvious how to make sense of these off diagonal elements so the best thing to do is to *diagonalise* the matrix by writing it in the "correct" basis (which is the eigenbasis of the matrix). Here is an example operator (using $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ as the basis states of my two-state system):

\begin{align}
    \hat{\rho} &= \frac{1}{2}|0\rangle\langle 0| + \frac{1}{2}|1\rangle\langle 1| + \frac{1}{4}|1\rangle\langle 0| + \frac{1}{4}|0\rangle\langle 1|\\
\end{align}

By finding the eigenvalues and eigenstates of this operator we see it can be written in the following form (multiply it out if you don't believe me):

\begin{align}
    \hat{\rho} &= \frac{3}{4} |\psi\rangle\langle\psi| + \frac{1}{4}|\phi\rangle\langle\phi|\\
    |\psi\rangle &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|0\rangle+|1\rangle\right)\\
    |\phi\rangle &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|0\rangle-|1\rangle\right)\\
\end{align}

And now the interpretation is easy. We have a mixed state equivalent to that produced by creating the state $|\psi\rangle$ with probability $\frac{3}{4}$ and the state  $|\phi\rangle$ with probability $\frac{1}{4}$.

In general if your density matrix has off diagonal entries and you need a physical interpretation your first step should be to diagonalise it.

A coherent state is a totally different thing. It is a state formed of a system* with a particle in a harmonic potential $$\hat{H} = \hbar\omega\left(\hat{X}^2 + \hat{P}^2 \right)$$ Note that this system has *continuous* degrees of freedom (the particle can be in any position) unlike the last one which only had a two dimensional state-space. Specifically a coherent state is any of the *eigenvectors* of the annihilation operator for this system. A coherent state can be written in the following form ($|n\rangle$ is the number eigenstate with $n$ quanta of energy):

\begin{align}
|\alpha\rangle = e^{\frac{-|\alpha|^2}{2}}\sum_n \frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}}|n\rangle
\end{align}

* Or any system which can be written in an equivalent way